# Operator = with abstract class C++ OOP

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, operator-overloading, abstract-class

I have class Employee

```
class Employee{
protected:
 char* name
public:
 Employee();
 virtual ~Employee();
 float getSalary() = 0; // pure virtual funtion
 virtual Employee& operator = (const Employe& temp);
}
```

and derived class productEmployee

```
class productEmployee:public Employee{
protected:
 int product;
public:
 productEmployee();
 virutal ~productEmployee();
 float getSalary();
 virtual productEmployee& operator = (const productEmployee& temp);
}
```

Operator= for two classes
class Employee

```
Employee& Employee::operator = (const Employee& temp) {
    if (this != &temp) {
        this->~Employee();
        name = new char[100]();
        strcpy_s(name, 100, temp.name);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

class productEmployee

```
productEmployee& productEmployee::operator = (const productEmployee& temp) {
    if (this != &temp) {
        //this->~productEmployee();
        Employee::operator=(temp);
        product = temp.product
    }
    return *this;
}
```

when I create in main like:

```
Employee *t1 = new productEmployee()
Employee *t2 = new productEmployee()
t1->input()...
*t2=*t1 //(t2=t1 is wrong, memory leak)
```

It doesn't work, t1,and t2 now have same address, I want t1!=t2 and also t1->name != t2->name (address), how can I edit operator= to get that?

Comment: `this->~productEmployee();` looks super wrong.

Comment: Please make sure that the [mre] you show us is properly copy-pasted. We can tell because there's no such thing as a `Class` (with upper-case `C`) in C++. Any chance of other unrelated errors or problems will just make it harder for us to help you with the problem you really have.

Comment: Thanks, operator= in Employee had it.

Comment: And `t2=t1` is a *pointer* assignment. It will, as you state, make `t1` and `t2` point to the same object, loosing the one you originally created for `t2`. Which is a memory leak.

Comment: I type it again myself, my code is  VietNamese, so I convert into English.

Comment: -Some programmer dude, so how about *t2=*t1?

Comment: – Some programmer dude: yes, debug it only call NhanVien =, so t2->product =0. How to fix it?

Comment: You don't want `operator=` for polymorphic classes *at all*. The only sensible definition is `void operator=(const Employe&) = delete;`. This will make `*t2 = *t1` or any such thing a compilation error.

Answer (score 2):

Your recent change makes the code better, but will still not invoke your assignment operator.

That's because you don't *override* the assignment operator in the child class. To override a virtual function you must use the exact same arguments and qualifiers. I suggest you get in the habit of using the `override` special identifiers for all your overridden function, as that will cause the compiler to complain if you don't actually override a function. As can be seen [here](https://godbolt.org/z/13EeG6r7j) (please note that I fixed numerous other errors in your code to make it work).

As a simple solution, don't use virtual assignment operators at all. Instead only have the (non-virtual) assignment operator in the base `Employee` class, which then call a virtual `copy` (or similarly named) function. The `productEmployee` class overrides it (properly), and *downcast* the argument to the right type inside.

Perhaps something like this:

```
class Employee
{
    // Other functions and members

protected:
    virtual Employee& copy(Employee const& other)
    {
        // TODO: Implement copying of Employee objects...

        return *this;
    }

public:
    Employee& operator=(Employee const& other)
    {
        return copy(other);
    }
};

class productEmployee : public Employee
{
    // Other functions and members

protected:
    Employee& copy(Employee const& other) override
    {
        productEmployee const& real_other = static_cast<productEmployee const&>(other);

        // TODO: Implement copying of productEmployee objects, using real_other...

        // This is needed to invoke the parents copy function
        return Employee::copy(other);
    }
};
```

After this change, your (proper object) assignment

```
*t2 = *t1;
```

should work fine (assuming the `copy` function do what they should).

---

On the note of the `copy` function doing what it should, you could make it much simpler by not using `char*` for strings. Use `std::string` for all your strings, and copying the string is a matter of simple assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Answer above from Some programmer dude, from this, I have solved this by my way here:

class Employee

```
virtual NhanVien* clone() = 0;
```

class productEmployee

```
Employee* productEmployee::clone() {
    productEmployee* p = new productEmployee();
    if (p == NULL) return NULL;
    strcpy_s(p->name, 100, this->name);
    p->product = this->product;
    return p;
}
```

And now I only need

```
NhanVien *t2 = t1->clone(); // It works with me
```